# What's the right way to use babel-jest?

Tags: babeljs, jestjs, babel-jest

Per the docs: https://github.com/facebook/jest#babel-integration

> If you'd like to use Babel, it can easily be enabled: `npm install --save-dev babel-jest babel-polyfill`

So all you have to do is install those two packages and nothing else? Everything else works the same way? `npm test` will just know you want to use `babel-jest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will recognise that you want use babel and use your `.babelrc` file to configure babel. And of cause you have to install babel as well.